# Positive and Negative Dual Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice

I want to build a dual power supply board that works with 12V DC from the power adapter and gives +/-15V at its output. I came across a schematic in [LT3094](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3094.pdf) datasheet on pg 30.

[image]

I am trying to simulate this in LTSpice but cannot get the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Link to schematic: https://mega.nz/file/JZ5FQTpL#55EwcdgKTL5lGB_d8FJHPtzrqKkTLHKl2kBKqHNin0E

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the simulation using different value for the 150k pots (Rset)?  You're using a 150K fixed value in the second schematic for each. Many of the datasheet examples use a value of 33.2K.  Try that value, or at least go to 50% of the full pot value.

Comment: I changed the Rset values to 33.2k. The output is the same as before.

Comment: @courageouslywin What does "cannot get the desired output" mean? What is the desired output? How is the simulation output different to the desired output? If you add the output of the simulation to your question, then we may be able to help you. Please add the waveforms that you think indicate that you have a problem, and please explain why you think you have a problem.

Comment: By desired output, I mean that when I probe Vpos and Vneg in the simulation, it should give +15V and -15V, respectively.

Comment: "Please add the waveforms that you think indicate that you have a problem, and please explain why you think you have a problem."